# Confluence requirements page - how to link feature to stories automatically?

Tags: jira, integration, confluence

I've integrated Confluence and JIRA. I'm using Confluence product requirement page to capture my requirement. However in the header section where we link Epic from JIRA, I'm acutally linking Feature from JIRA. We dont use Epic in our project. For us JIRA hierarchy is like Project => Feature => Story

So I attached/created feature in Epic field of Produect requirment page of Confluence and then I created stories on that Confluence page. My epxectation is thoese stories should get linked automatically with Feature in JIRA. However it won't.

Any clue on how I can achieve this?

Please note it works well in case of Epic.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is any way around this behavior. Confluence expects the top of the hierarchy to be an Epic. I am assuming that you are using issue links to enforce the Project to Feature hierarchy, but Confluence doesn't know about these links.